# Passing template strings into array.filter operation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have some code that compares two arrays and filters data, that looks like this:

```
const recordsToUpdate = await sourceArr.filter(e => targetArr.find(obj => obj.id === e.id_number) !== undefined);
```

What I'd like to do is find a way to pass in dynamic variables for the properties being matched on here, so I can reuse this code.

Can I do this with backticks and template strings - or some other way?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
const recordsToUpdate = await sourceArr.filter(`e => targetArr.find(obj => obj.${targetProp} === e.${sourceProp}) !== undefined`);
```

Is there some syntax available that will allow me to do this?

Comment: just use `obj[targetProp]` and `e[sourceProp]` instead

Comment: Have you tried obj[targetProp] , Another way to access properties in a object..

Comment: If you convert your `targetArr` to a `Set` of each `targetProp`, then your `filter()` can become O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: Also `filter()` is synchronous, unless your `sourceArr` is not a JavaScript `Array`, so there's no need to `await` it

Answer (score 1):

You can access object property by this syntaxes:

```
const recordsToUpdate = await sourceArr.filter(e => targetArr.find(obj => obj[targetProp] === e[sourceProp]) !== undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```js
const findRecords = (key1, key2) => {
  // No need to use await
  return sourceArr.filter(e => targetArr.find(obj => obj[key1] === e[key2]) !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: Use the names in the question. `targetProp` and `sourceProp` are much more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `targetProp` and `sourceProp` in bracket notation, you should convert your `targetArr` to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to decrease the time complexity of the `filter()` method from O(m * n) to O(m + n). You can use a curried function and a closure to do this without creating the `Set` in the global scope:

```
const filterBy = (targetArr, targetProp) => {
  const targetSet = new Set(targetArr.map(obj => obj[targetProp]));

  return (sourceArr, sourceProp) => (
    soureArr.filter(obj => targetSet.has(obj[sourceProp]))
  );
};

// example usage
const filterByTargetProp = filterBy(targetArr, targetProp);
// filterByTargetProp() is a reusable function
const recordsToUpdate = filterByTargetProp(sourceArr, sourceKey);
```